# Shell script fails on Docker for windows

Tags: shell, docker

I'm facing a problem trying to run an image on Docker for Windows.

I have a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
WORKDIR /myworkdir
COPY path/tomyproject/src/main/bin/start /myworkdir/start
...
EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "sh", "/myworkdir/start" ]
```

And here is a piece that fails on "start" file:

```
#!/bin/sh

SCRIPT="$0"
# set the environment variables received from the command line
for i; do
case "$i" in
  *=*) echo $i ;
  key=${i%=*}
  value=${i#*=};
  export $key=$value
esac
done
```

I have not problem building and running this into a Mac however on Windows (Docker for windows) i can't run it and got this message:

> : not found myworkdir/start: line 4:
>   /myworkdir/start: line 6: syntax error: unexpected word (expecting "do")

If someone is familiar with this and know how to resolve it, please help !!

Comment: What is the script trying to do?

Comment: Have you edited the file on Windows? Could this be a Windows end-of-line issue?

Comment: I have not edited the file on Windows, as i said in post, i run on this in Mac OS with not problem. So, i was expecting the same behave on Windows. I mean, that's the advantage of using docker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to delete the character `\r` in the script `start`, for example:

`sed -i 's/\r//g' start`

Then copy the script `start` to windows and rebuild the image